# Using git from Package Manager Console in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, git, github, console, nuget

I'm trying to use `git` from Package Manager Console window in Visual Studio 2010. And most `git` commands running as expected, except network-related.

When I tried `git push origin master` Studio stops responding. The code were pushed to github.com account. I've noticed that `ssh-*` applications were fired and start hanging in system memory, so I switched to `https` authentication. But the Studio still not responding (and there is no `ssh` related stuff in memory).

Does anybody knows how overcome this issue?

Comment: I doubt it is network related but rather that git is trying to prompt for credentials and the PowerShell window doesn't know what to do with that.

Answer (score 2):

Any reason that you can't drop down to MSysGit and use the package manager, along with git, from there? That would be my approach. Plus you get all benefits of bash.

Comment: Nice idea! But it seems to be Entity Framework commands are not registered outside Visual Studio. Any idea, how I can successfully run `Update-Database` from bare Windows Powershell?

Comment: I'm sure there is a way.. For example, I can easily launch Visual Studio from bash with `start mysolution.sln`. Database updating is done via a version script. I use NHibernate and it can export the difference between the model and the db schema as script.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your github account setted on generic credentials in windows credential manager?

I'm using Git on my Nuget Package Manager for a while now with the credentials saved on windows without any problem. I use also posh-git on my Package Manager that help me a lot.