# Use NuGet PowerShell commandlets from outside Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, powershell, nuget

I was trying to use my favorite source control from the Package Manager console in Visual Studio 2010. I had issues described in another [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12862891/using-git-from-package-manager-console-in-visual-studio). For now the best answer is to move all command-line stuff from Visual Studio to bare PowerShell.

But this case the Visual Studio related commandlets are not working. For example, most crucial one — I cannot run `Update-Database` command from [Entity Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework).

Is it possible to register somehow Visual Studio specific commandlets for the current project in PowerShell? Or make PowerShell automatically take current project context from the `packages` subfolder?

Comment: I had to quit using nuget due to its limited support of command line commands. I cannot use it in Jenkins properly.

Comment: I have the same problem. Still seaerching for a solution.

Answer (score 13):

The NuGet PowerShell commands rely on being run from within Visual Studio so will not work outside in the normal PowerShell running from the command line.

You can however use [migrate.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618307.aspx) which ships with the EntityFramework NuGet package and use that from the command line to update your database.

As a prototype I put together a way to use [NuGet PowerShell commands from the normal PowerShell command line using SharpDevelop](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/mattward/archive/2011/06/12/InstallingNuGetPackagesOutsideVisualStudio.aspx). Unfortunately at the moment the EntityFramework NuGet package does not work with SharpDevelop.

Another interesting project is [StudioShell](http://studioshell.codeplex.com/) which provides a new DTE: drive inside Visual Studio but can also be used outside from the command line. I do not believe it supports NuGet PowerShell commands being run from the normal PowerShell command line.

Answer (score 10):

I can find the NuGet.psd1 file at:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\5ttpefif.3mk\Modules\NuGet\NuGet.psd1.`

However, when you try to load it:

```
PS> Import-Module $pathToNuGetPsd1 -Force -NoClobber -Scope Global
Import-Module : The name of the current Windows PowerShell host is: 'ConsoleHost'.
The module 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\
Extensions\5ttpefif.3mk\Modules\NuGet\NuGet.psd1' requires the following Windows
PowerShell host: 'Package Manager Host'.
```

I think we're out of luck.  It has to be run from the Package Manager Host and requires things from Visual Studio as stated by Matt.

To solve my problem I used Chocolatey to install NuGet.CommandLine and then used NuGet.bat to do what I needed.  It is a little more work and may not work in all cases depending on what you're trying to do.

Chocolatey: https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey/wiki/Installation

NuGet.CommandLine:

```
PS> cinst NuGet.CommandLine
```

Comment: You can change the console host name by this code `$host.gettype().GetField('nameResult', 'Instance, NonPublic').setValue($host, 'Package Manager Host')`, but then there's some more errors.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not terribly familiar with the Visual Studio cmdlets, but you can import a module into your PowerShell session by using `Import-Module -Name <ModuleName>`. You can list the available (aka. "installed") PowerShell modules by using `Get-Module -ListAvailable'.

My guess would be that the Visual Studio cmdlets are contained with its own PowerShell module, but it's quite possible that it's not "installed" to one of the standard locations in `$env:PSModulePath`. If this is the case, then you might need to locate the module directory and import either the .psd1 or .psm1 file directly, and pass that into: `Import-Module -Name <FullPathToModuleFile>`.

As an example of the above, take notice of where the Windows Azure PowerShell module is located: http://trevorsullivan.net/2012/06/07/introducing-microsofts-official-windows-azure-powershell-module/

It's under the Program Files directory, and is not immediately available to PowerShell, unless you import the module from its fully qualified path (the .psd1 module manifest file).

Hope this helps.