# What is the best way of scripting nuget commands?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, powershell, jenkins, nuget

I'm quite new to Continous Integration and I'm trying to make some scripts for NuGet. It seems that the only way to make such scripts is the NuGet command line commands.

The NuGet command line doesn't offer so many functionality like the Package Manager Console in VS2010.

What is the usual way of do such scripting?

I need simple operations such as changing the version, updating the packages, etc...

Thanks!

Comment: This question is very hard to answer as it is very broad and difficult to tell exactly what is being asked. Could you clarify it with maybe an example of what you tried in updating a package and the error you received?

Comment: @Goyuix: you're right, my english is also not so good. But basically, I try to use the powershell cmdlet "Update-Package" from the package manager console in a normal PowerShell console and it is not available. I've tried to find where are these commands and I cannot find them.

Comment: You can import Powershell packages - `Import-Module -Name <FullPathToModuleFile>.` There is a similar question asked earlier. Please check the following link (might help) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12884282/use-nuget-powershell-commandlets-from-outside-visual-studio

Comment: If you don't like the command line reference, you can create a custom MSBuildTask.  The Custom MSBuild Task is just a fancy way to call the command line.......you set properties on the Task....and then the internal code wires up all the command line stuff super nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only for completion and to share my experiences, I will tell you what I did:

I used some of the command line tools, the functionality is quite limited, but for some easy tasks is ok.

For more complex tasks, the powershell snippets are the best option. They have to be integrated in Visual studio and can be only used within Visual Studio. It is possible to use tham also as a script, but it is necessary a lot of work to make it work.

At the very end, I'm not using nuget anymore, it doesn't really fits the needs of a software development team for internal work. It is quite good for releasing new version of your software to the internet but this is all. It cannot really be compared with MAVEN.