# How to determine the version of nuget that is currently running from inside init.ps1

Tags: powershell, nuget

Inside a nuget init.ps1 https://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-package#automatically-running-powershell-scripts-during-package-installation-and-removal  how do i get access to the current running version of nuget so as to do some switching logic on it?

Note I am running inside the Visual Studio context

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use NuGet powershell commandlets from outside Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12884282/use-nuget-powershell-commandlets-from-outside-visual-studio)

Comment: @juanvan how is that other question the same as this one? i am not running outside of VS

Comment: It is in the Help of VS, running dir *.exe | %{ $_.VersionInfo } gave me a version of 1.0.0.0 and that is not right on the nuget.exe found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the NuGet assembly file version and the product version in init.ps1 using the following:

```
// Returns the file version (e.g. 2.8.60723.765) as a string
$package.GetType().Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString()

// Returns the product version (e.g. 2.8.7) as a string
[System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($package.GetType().Assembly.Location).ProductVersion
```

Comment: OH wow? since $package.GetType() resolves to a nuget runtime type?

Comment: Yes it should resolve to a NuGet runtime type at least it does for NuGet v2. I have not tried this with NuGet v3.

Answer (score 0):

Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object {$_.name -like "*nuget*"}
You will need to know the version of VS too, having 12 and 13 has 2 versions of VS.

Comment: that is all versions installed. not the current running version