# How do you get prerelease packages using powershell's Find-Package?

Tags: powershell, nuget

I am using [Find-Package](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn890709.aspx) from Powershell 5.0. I need to query for pre-release packages. Is this possible?

I am aware that I can fall back to using `nuget.exe list -prerelease` if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the `-AllVersions` parameter will include them.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [nuget powershell documentation](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-manager-console-powershell-reference) there is the `-IncludePreRelease` option:

> Find-Package [Id] [-Source ] [-First ] [-Skip ] [-AllVersions] [-IncludePrerelease] [-ExactMatch]

Test:

> PM> Find-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework -Exact
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Entity... **{2.2.1}**
>
> PM> Find-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework -Exact -IncludePreRelease
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Entity... **{3.0.0-rc1-final}**

Comment: Yeah, oddly enough, `-IncludePrerelease` only works inside of Visual Studio. It does _not_ exist in a powershell prompt.

Comment: It seems visual studio uses a Powershell module named `nuget` which is different from module `PackageManagement` outside VS. Interesting difference as prerelease option has nothing VS-specific about it. [Related post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22256792/331325)

Answer (score 0):

In Powershell you have to use the command "-AllowPrereleaseVersions" as documented here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/module/packagemanagement/find-package?view=powershell-7.1

Here is the hint on the differences betweeen PackageManager in Visual Studio and in Powershell:
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/nuget/reference/ps-reference/ps-ref-find-package

> Version 3.0+; this topic describes the command within the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio on Windows. For the generic PowerShell Find-Package command, see the PowerShell PackageManagement reference.